# How do i use $_GET to check whether the value of the sub category is in a category?

Tags: php, mysqli, get

I am making a forum system to strengthen my php and make a website for a community that i have. I do not know how to check if the sub category i have selected is inside the specified category for example we have `localhost/forum/sub_category.php?cat=1&sub_cat=1` what i want to know is to figure out if a user tries to set the category id to 3 and the sub_category to 4 and the sub_category id does not exist. How do i use $_GET to check for that, then show the user a message saying that the specified sub category does not exist. Here's My Code:

```
<?php

include '../inc/dbc.php';
include '../inc/functions.php'
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
    $my_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $firstname = getuser($username, 'firstname');
    $lastname = getuser($username, 'lastname');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EWC Forums</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include 'header.php';?>

        <div class='main'>
            <div class='body'>
                <div class='left'>
                    <?php
                        if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['sub_cat'])) {
                            $cat_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories Where");// this is not done yet
                        } else if ($_GET['sub_cat'] == 0) {
                            $msg = 'That Sub Category Was Not Found In Our Database';
                        } else {
                    ?>  
                        <div class='message'><?php echo $msg;?></div>
                    <?php   
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                <div class='right'>

                </div>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

This is the main page that shows the categories and the sub_categories:

```
<?php

include '../inc/dbc.php';
include '../inc/functions.php'
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
    $my_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $firstname = getuser($username, 'firstname');
    $lastname = getuser($username, 'lastname');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EWC Forums</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include 'header.php';?>

        <div class='main'>
            <div class='body'>
            <?php
                if(loggedIn() == false) {
            ?>
                <div class='mbli'>You Are Not Logged In Right Now. Click Here To <a href="login.php">Login</a></div><br>
            <?php
                }
            ?>
                <div class='forum'>
                <div class='tools'>
                    <?php
                        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM users WHERE rank = 'Administrator' ");
                        $res = mysqli_num_rows($sql);
                        if ($sql == 1) {
                    ?>
                        <div class='forummenu'>
                            <a href="create_category.php"><i class=''></i> New Category</a>
                            <a href="create_subcategory.php"><i class=''></i> New Sub Category</a>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
                    <?php
                        $check_forum = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM categories");
                        while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($check_forum)) {
                            $cat_id = $run['cat_id'];
                            $creator = $run['creator'];
                            $cat_name = $run['name'];
                            $create_date = $run['create_date'];
                            $activated = $run['activated'];
                    ?>
                    <div class='cat'>
                        <style type="text/css">
                        .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
                        .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                        .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;}
                        .tg .tg-7ht0{background-color:#f07075;color:#ffffff}
                        </style>
                        <table>
                          <tr class="cat_head">
                            <th class="tg-7ht0"><b><?php echo $cat_name;?></b><i><?php echo $create_date;?></i></th>
                            <th class="tg-7ht0">Threads</th>
                            <th class="tg-7ht0">Posts</th>
                            <th class="tg-7ht0">Latest Posts</th>
                          </tr>
                    <?php
                            $check_subcat = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE cat_id= '$cat_id' ");
                            while ($run_sub = mysqli_fetch_array($check_subcat)) {
                                $sub_cat_id = $run_sub['sub_cat_id'];
                                $creator_subcat = $run_sub['creator'];
                                $name_sub = $run_sub['name'];
                                $sub_desc = $run_sub['sub_desc'];
                                $create_date_sub = $run_sub['create_date'];
                    ?>
                              <tr class='sub_cat'>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0"><div class='sub_img'><img src="http://minotar.net/helm/<?php echo $creator_subcat;?>/32"></div><div class='sub_body'><a href='sub_category.php?cat=<?php echo $cat_id;?>&sub_cat=<?php echo $name_sub;?>'><div class='sub_tit'><b><?php echo $name_sub; ?></b><div class='desc'><?php echo $sub_desc;?></div></div></a><i class='date'><?php echo $create_date_sub; ?></i></div></td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">0</td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">0</td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">Nub picture</td>
                              </tr>
                    <?php
                            }

                    ?>
                              <div class='clear'></div>
                            </table>
                        </div>
                    <?php
                        }
                    ?>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```

Also if there's another way to do this please suggest it, but i do prefer this one. And if you need more code just ask.

Comment: You should validate category and subcategory from database before going deep in code.

Comment: you forget to initialized the session at the top of your page

Comment: the session is initialized in the functions.php file

Comment: You don't really need to know the category for the subcategory. If you made the db correctly then the sub cat has a `cat_id` If you want to output the name of the upper category you will use that id to check in the `categories` table and show it's name...

Comment: i added a bit more code

Comment: @ClementAbel a tip, to keep your own database tables understandable in the furher only use `id` for PK's and for FK's you'd use `short_table_name_id`

Comment: when ever i try to add foreign keys it never works, so i haven't bothered with  them to the extent that i've forgotten how

Comment: Which kind of FK's? Nullable or not nullable?

Comment: not null i think, i can't really remember

Comment: Not null uses constraints and nullable is pretty much inline as far as I am aware of.

Answer (score 1):

Try use this :
**EDIT**: with the sub categories screenshot on comments :

```
<?php
    if (isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['sub_cat'])) {
        $cat_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM SubCategoryTableName WHERE sub_cat_id='".$_GET['sub_cat']."' AND cat_id ='".$_GET['cat']."'");// this is not done yet

        // Check if number of ROWS are zero/sub category notfound! .

        if(mysqli_num_rows($cat_query)) == 0)
        {
            // show error and die
            die('The requested sub/category not found.');
        }

    } else if ($_GET['sub_cat'] == 0) {
        $msg = 'That Sub Category Was Not Found In Our Database';
    } else {
?>
```

Please note this code are work , but always must secure the inputs that requested from users.

Comment: @ClementAbel , the answer was edited with the SubCategory structure screenshot , but I don't know the subcategory table name then repace the `SubCategoryTableName` with your's .

Comment: oh ok and it was called `subcategories`

Comment: it is showing me an empty page with no errors, i think it has something to do with the quotation marks.

Comment: @ClementAbel , yes a one more quotation mark that's on query . use the new query of this answer.

Comment: re use it , a second quotation mark is not included too , after the first edit .

Comment: it is still coming up as a blank page

Comment: may have a problem on syntax , please use this code `ini_set('display_errors',1);  error_reporting(E_ALL);` at start of customer.php to determine of errors on page .

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if your id's will go further up automatically otherwise you just put a check statement to see if the cat and sub cat are the correct number and not too high or low.

If you do depend on your database then you could ask a query to see if it exists or not or ask it to give the latest id in the database and use this then to check if your id is lower than that.

I hope that I understood your question correctly here. Don't forget to validate your GET request btw ;)

Answer (score 0):

Thanks for all the help, because of you guys i figured how to fix the problem, it may not be the correct way but it's close. Here's my code:

```
<?php

include '../inc/dbc.php';
include '../inc/functions.php'
?>
<?php
if(isset($_GET['user']) && !empty($_GET['user'])) {
    $username = $_GET['user'];
} else {
    $username = $_SESSION['username'];
}
    $my_name = $_SESSION['username'];
    $firstname = getuser($username, 'firstname');
    $lastname = getuser($username, 'lastname');
?>
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <head>
        <title>EWC Forums</title>
        <link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="css/index.css">
    </head>

    <body>
        <?php include 'header.php';?>

        <div class='main'>
            <div class='body'>
                    <?php
                        if(isset($_GET['cat']) && isset($_GET['sub_cat'])) {
                        $sub = $_GET['sub_cat'];
                        $cat = $_GET['cat'];
                        $sql = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM subcategories WHERE sub_cat_id = '$sub' AND cat_id = '$cat' ");
                        if (!$sql) {
                            $msg = 'Sorry We Kept Looking, But We Found Nothing ;-;';
                        } else {
                            if (mysqli_num_rows($sql) == 0) {
                                $msg = 'Ask An Admin';
                            } else {
                        ?>
                            <?php
                                while ($row = mysqli_fetch_array($sql)) {
                            ?>


                            <div class='cat'>
                                <style type="text/css">
                                .tg  {border-collapse:collapse;border-spacing:0;}
                                .tg td{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;word-break:normal;}
                                .tg th{font-family:Arial, sans-serif;font-size:14px;font-weight:normal;border-style:solid;border-width:1px;overflow:hidden;}
                                .tg .tg-7ht0{background-color:#f07075;color:#ffffff}
                                </style>
                                <table>
                                  <tr class="cat_head">
                                    <th class="tg-7ht0"><b><?php echo $row['name'];?></b><i><?php echo $row['create_date'];?></i></th>
                                    <th class="tg-7ht0">Views</th>
                                    <th class="tg-7ht0">Replies</th>
                                    <th class="tg-7ht0">Latest Posts</th>
                                  </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        $thread_query = mysqli_query($mysqli, "SELECT * FROM threads WHERE sub_cat_id = $sub ");
                                        while ($run = mysqli_fetch_array($thread_query)) {
                                            $thread_id = $run['thread'];
                                            $thread_author = $run['creator'];
                                            $thread_title = $run['name'];
                                            $thread_date = $run['create_date'];
                                    ?>
                                      <tr class='sub_cat'>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0"><div class='sub_img'><img src="http://minotar.net/helm/<?php echo $thread_author; ?>/32"></div><div class='sub_body'><a href=''><b><?php echo $thread_title; ?></b></a >&nbsp;created by <a href='profile.php?user=<?php echo $thread_author;?>'><?php echo $thread_author;?></a> at <?php echo $thread_date; ?></div></td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">0</td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">0</td>
                                <td class="tg-7ht0">Nub picture</td>
                              </tr>
                                    <?php
                                        }
                                }
                            ?>
                                        <div class='clear'></div>
                                    </table>
                                </div>
                            <?php
                            }
                        }
                    } else {
                    ?>
                        <div class='message'><?php echo $msg; ?></div>
                    <?php
                    }
                    ?>
                <div class='clear'></div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </body>
</html>
```